# How to make a nested map as dot separated strings of key and value in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a `Map[String, Any]`. The value can be another `Map` and so on.

```
val m: Map[String, Any] = Map("a" -> Map("b" -> Map("c" -> 1, "d" -> 4)))
```

What is the best way to convert this nested `Map` into another `Map` with values like

```
Map("a.b.c" -> 1, "a.b.d" -> 4)
```

Comment: what happened when you implemented it?

Comment: I am very new to scala. So, i wasn't able to implement it.

Comment: Well, did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use recursion as in any other programming language (it's not something Scala-specific).

```
val m: Map[String, Any] = Map("a" -> Map("b" -> Map("c" -> 1, "d" -> 4)))

def traverse(el: Any, acc: List[String] = List.empty[String]): Map[String, Int] = el match {
  case leaf: Int => Map(acc.reverse.mkString(".") -> leaf)
  case m: Map[String, Any] => m flatMap {
    case (k, v) => traverse(v, k :: acc)
  }
}

traverse(m)

res2_2: Map[String, Int] = Map("a.b.c" -> 1, "a.b.d" -> 4)
```

Btw,

1) the presented solution is not tail-recursive (so might throw stack-overflow on very deep trees) - you could write tail-recursive version as an exercise. Hint - you would need an accumulator for resulting collection (or use mutable buffer, idn, maybe you're not really into functional programming and was forced to use Scala by employer :) ).

2) `List` is inappropriate structure for accumulator (coz of [performance](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html)), I was just lazy to use less common one, as you were lazy to try to at least somehow implement this trivial algorithm. I bet there should be a duplicate question on SO, but again, lazy to look for it :).

3) `@unchecked` annotation would be appropriate at some place in my code (guess where?). And also default case for pattern matching (you can build a test case that breaks my function to figure out why).